# Is angular momentum conserved in $e$-$e$ scattering?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, angular-momentum

Consider the collision of two electrons. Naturally, these two charges will exert and equal and opposite force on each other causing scattering.

Jackson and others calculate the energy loss due to this scattering event (at least classically) but do not make any mention of angular momentum losses. Is angular momentum conserved for pair-wise $e$-$e$ interactions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the total angular momentum is conserved, and the total energy too, but if you are interested in changes of those quantities of the incident (not target) electron, they are not conserved.